# Eigenvector methods for system ODE

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

The question is to find the solution for 
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=2x+5y$$ $$\frac{dy}{dt}=-x-2y$$
What I have done is to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}
       \ 2 & 5            \\
       \ -1 & -2            
     \end{bmatrix}$$ 
And solve for eigenvectors $$\lambda_1=i, x_1=[2+i,-1];\lambda_2=-i,x_2=[i-2,1]$$
However my solution for $(x,y)$ is $$x(t)=C_1(2\cos t-\sin t)+iC_2(\cos t+2\sin t)$$ $$y(t)=C_1(-\cos t)+iC_2(-\sin t)$$No matter what I try, I cannot reach the answer given which the question asks me to show such that, for constant $\alpha$ and $\beta$, 
$$x(t)=\alpha (5\cos t)+\beta(5\sin t)$$
$$y(t)=\alpha(-2\cos t-\sin t)+\beta(\cos t -2\sin t)$$
I don't know what steps am I missing or what linear combinations should I looking for to reach the given solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ODE system can be written as

$$
\frac{{\rm d}u(t)}{{\rm d}t} = A u(t) \tag{1}
$$

with

$$
A = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 2 & 5 \\ -1 & -2\end{array}\right)
$$

and $u(t) = (x(t), y (t))^T$. The formal solution of Eq. (1) is

$$
u(t) = e^{At}u(0) \tag{2}
$$

In order to calculate $e^{At}$ we solve the eigensystem $A = U\Lambda U^{-1}$ and find

$$
U = \left(\begin{array}{cc} -2-i & -2 + i \\ 1 & 1\end{array}\right) ~~~\mbox{and}~~~ \Lambda = \left(\begin{array}{cc} i & 0 \\ 0 & -i\end{array}\right) 
$$

Therefore Eq. (2) becomes

$$
u(t) = U\left(\begin{array}{cc} e^{it} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-it}\end{array}\right) U^{-1}\left(\begin{array}{c} x_0 \\ y_0\end{array}\right)  = \left(\begin{array}{c} x_0\cos t + (2x_0 + 5y_0)\sin t \\ y_0\cos t - (x_0 + 2y_0)\sin t\end{array}\right)  \tag{3}
$$

where $x_0 = x(0)$ and $y_0 = y(0)$. Now, from Eq (3) define $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $5\alpha = x_0$ and $5\beta = (2x_0 + 5y_0)$, solving for $x_0$ and $y_0$ we find

$$
x_0 = 5\alpha ~~~\mbox{and}~~~ y_0 = \beta - 2\alpha
$$

With this Eq. (3) becomes

$$
\left(\begin{array}{c} x(t) \\ y(t)\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c} \alpha(5\cos t) + \beta(5\sin t) \\ \alpha(-2\cos t - \sin t) +\beta (\cos t - 2\sin t)\end{array}\right)
$$